# Setup Multiple Sales Channels on same domain, and getting 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, http-status-code-500, shopware

I have two sales channels. One for Sweden and one for Nigeria.

In Nigeria I will my products in NGN and use the local language, English.
In Sweden I will let the user pick either Swedish or English, but the currency is in SEK.

**Domain settings for Nigeria Sales Channel**

[image]

**Domain settings for Sweden Sales Channel**
[image]

It worked well with the Swedish sales channel  and the two domains, but when I added the Nigerian sales channel and its domain (same) I got a 500 Internal Server Error on /public/en-ng, but it still works on /public/sv-se and /public/en-se. Any clue how to get the /public/en-ng working?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy fix. Somehow it needed manually be activated. After activating this it worked!

[image]